# Form Validation in JavaScript-html

Tags: javascript, html

I've built a simple website that contains three pages. I created a form in home page and something goes wrong with my JavaScript - I'm having a problem in setting a field right next to the input field with a relevant message to the user telling him what they did wrong(prompt).
so I'm inputting below the homepage (the form which is in the body of the page -html) and the script itself which includes a simple function.

My purpose is to check if user fills the field name and after that they delete it, so I want to display a red color message that tells the user that this field is required.
I'd be glad if someone can help me with that.

```js
function validateName(){
  var name=document.getElementById("fullName").value;
  if (name.length == null)
  {
    nameRequiredPromt("Name Is Required",fullNamePrompt,"white");
    return false;
  }
}

function nameRequiredPromt(message,promtLocation,color){
  document.getElementById(promtLocation).innerHTML=message;
  document.getElementById(promtLocation).style.color=color;
}
```

```html
<form id="form" style="color:white;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
      FullName :
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" placeholder="fullName" id="fullName" 
        onkeyup="validateName()" type="text"/> <label id="fullNamePrompt">aaaa 
        </label> <br>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
      E-mail :
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="email" placeholder="email" id="email"/><label 
        id="emailPrompt"> </label><br>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
      New Password :
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="password" placeholder="password" id="newPassWord"/> <label 
            id="PasswordPrompt"> </label><br>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
      Repeat Password :
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="password" placeholder="repeatedPassword" 
        id="repeatedPassWord"/> <label id="repeatedPassWordPrompt"> </label><br>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>

      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit"/> <label 
        id="submitPrompt"> </label><br>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

I did some checks to be sure that the script works and it did work so I think my problem is in the declaration of the label "id".

Comment: can you tell us about any error reported by the console?

Comment: what is value of `fullNamePrompt` in function `validateName`?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
if (name && !name.length)
{
    nameRequiredPromt("Name Is Required","fullNamePrompt","white");
    return false;
}
```

first condition checks if name is null, second for checking if name.length is 0.

Answer (score 3):

switch

```
name.length == null
```

to

```
!name.length
```

`length` will be zero not null

also `fullNamePrompt` appears undefined

try `nameRequiredPromt("Name Is Required","fullNamePrompt","white");`

**Fixed**: `name.length == null` and also `fullNamePrompt` undefined and `color`: white to red

```js
function validateName(){
  var name=document.getElementById("fullName").value;
  if (!name.length)
  {
    nameRequiredPromt("Name Is Required","fullNamePrompt","red");
    return false;
  }
}

function nameRequiredPromt(message,promtLocation,color){
  document.getElementById(promtLocation).innerHTML=message;
  document.getElementById(promtLocation).style.color=color;
}
```

```html
<form id="form" style="color:white;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
      FullName :
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" placeholder="fullName" id="fullName" 
        onkeyup="validateName()" type="text"/> <label id="fullNamePrompt">aaaa 
        </label> <br>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
      E-mail :
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="email" placeholder="email" id="email"/><label 
        id="emailPrompt"> </label><br>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
      New Password :
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="password" placeholder="password" id="newPassWord"/> <label 
            id="PasswordPrompt"> </label><br>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
      Repeat Password :
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="password" placeholder="repeatedPassword" 
        id="repeatedPassWord"/> <label id="repeatedPassWordPrompt"> </label><br>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>

      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit" onclick="return validateName();"/> <label 
        id="submitPrompt"> </label><br>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: i did that and it didn't work i don't think its the problem . i think the problem is in the html code and not in the script itself

Comment: @ShahdKrayem then you have multiple problems as this is surely wrong. try a `console.log(name.length===0)` and check dev tools

Comment: @ShahdKrayem i've fixed your code and shown it below

Answer (score 0):

i redo your code  add what you want

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
   <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Title</title>
   <style>
     body {
        background: transparent; /* Make it white if you need */
        color: #fcbe24;
        padding: 0 24px;
        margin: 0;
        height: 100vh;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 
        Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
      }
    </style>
   </head>
  <body>

  <form id="form" style="color:white;">
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            FullName :
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" placeholder="fullName" id="fullName"
                   onkeyup="validateName()" type="text"/> 
                <label>  </label> <br>

        </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>
            E-mail :
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="email" placeholder="email" id="email"/> 
               <label> </label><br>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
            New Password :
        </td>
        <td>
             <input type="password" placeholder="password" id="newPassWord"/> <label> </label><br>
        </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>
            Repeat Password :
        </td>
         <td>
            <input type="password" placeholder="repeatedPassword"
                   id="repeatedPassWord"/> <label > </label><br>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit"/> 
      <label> </label><br>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

<script>
    function validateName() {

        var name = document.getElementById("fullName").value;

        if (!name.length) {
            nameRequiredPromt("Name Is Required", "fullName", "red");
            return;
        }
    }

    function nameRequiredPromt(message, promtLocation, color) {

        document.getElementById(promtLocation).nextElementSibling.innerHTML = message;
        document.getElementById(promtLocation).nextElementSibling.style.color = color;
        document.getElementById(promtLocation).style.borderColor = color;
    }

  </script>
  </form>
  </body>
  </html>
```